# cannot import graphql query files in jest vue

Tags: vue.js, jestjs, nuxt.js, apollo-client

I adding unit tests to my Nuxt/Vue project and I'm using Jest for unit testing, I'm fetching data from the server-side using Apollo Client and I have a problem with importing .gql files inside test files.

here is the query file **names.gql**

```
{
 names {
  created_at
  id
  name
  published_at
  updated_at
 }
}
```

I'm importing the query inside Vue component like this

```
import namesQuery from "@/queries/names";
```

**Test file:**

```
import { mount } from '@vue/test-utils';

import Names from '@/components/Names';

describe('Names', () => {
  test('is a Vue instance', () => {
    const wrapper = mount(Names)
    expect(wrapper.vm).toBeTruthy()
  })
})
```

When I run the tests, it says:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token '{'
```

**Please advise.**

Answer (score 2):

According to the graphql-tag documentation you need to use  jest-transform-graphql to handle imports.

Add this to your jest config file:

```
"transform": {
  "\\.(gql|graphql)$": "jest-transform-graphql",
}
```

and then let the party begin